# Why can't I compare two atom like this?

Tags: prolog

So basically here is some Prolog code I wrote, using GNU-Prolog 1.4.4.

```
A is 1,
B = (A == 2),
B == no.   


A is 2,
B = (A == 2),
B == no.
```

What I am expecting is when `A` is 2, then `B == no` returns `no`, when `A` is 1, then `B == no`  returns `yes`.

However, to my surprise, both two code snippets return `no`, which leaving me the impression that `B == no` works in an unexpected way..

So basically how can I write the code in the way I want?

Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: With B = (A == 2) you're bounding the expression A==2 to B (always true). This is different to evaluate A==2. Then you ask prolog if B is equal to 'no' and therefore the conjunction is always false. I think you have to check the concepts of bound and free variables, and the predicate evaluation principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
B = (A == 2)
```

does not compute `A==2` in any way and assign the result to `B`. It just unifies the term `B` (a variable) with the term `(A==2)`. The result of the unification is that `B` is now `A==2`. You can check yourself by omitting `B==no`:

```
?- A is 1, B=(A==2).
A = 1,
B = (1==2) ? 
yes
```

If you really want that `B` unifies with the atoms `yes` resp. `no` you can use an if-then-else construct:

```
( A == 2    -> B = yes
; otherwise -> B = no)
```